# How to fix "Error in trimriver - no remaining line segments" when using Riverdist?

Tags: r, qgis

I've been looking for solutions to calculate distance between sampling points and the river mouth/estuary, following the river line. It looks like "Riverdist" could solve all my issues but I'm having troubles from the start. I'm working on a national level (South Africa) but have been trying with single catchments first as the river systems qre quite big and complex.

What I have done :

- I made the river shp file as simple as possible and I deleted all  tributaries that are not necessary
- Used projected CRS
- Tried to load it using "line2network"

```
> library(riverdist)

> limpopo <- line2network(path = "/Volumes/Shadowfax/Distribution/simple rivers/Limpopo.shp", layer="Limpopo", tolerance = 100, reproject = NULL,
+              supplyprojection = NULL)
```

This is the error message I get : 
Error in trimriver(trim = problems, rivers = rivers) : 
  Error - resulting river network has no remaining line segments

My shp file looks totally fine to me.

I guess I'm doing something wrong when editing my shp or when saving it but I don't know what. Here's a glimpse of the shp : 
[Limpopo.shp](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13PWMYRSl_GHRVuS_B5v-y9PbrdM9JN00?usp=sharing)
I must add that I'm pretty much inexperienced with R or any kind of coding. This is my first go at "Riverdist".

Hope I can find help here ! Thank you !

[EDIT] Used MM answer. But I still have an issue. The river segments are not considered consecutive (if it makes sense) and it gets me in trouble later on, when calculating distance between points and the river mouth. I also tried to make the shp even more simple on QGIs before hand.

```
library(riverdist)

# Create your custom function to read the file. 
# Examine the line2network function and modify the lines that cause an issue with your specific shape file

my.custom.line2network =  function (path = ".", layer, tolerance = 100, reproject = NULL, supplyprojection = NULL) {
  sp <- suppressWarnings(rgdal::readOGR(dsn = path, layer = layer, verbose = F))
  if (class(sp) != "SpatialLinesDataFrame") 
    stop("Specified shapefile is not a linear feature.")
  if (is.na(sp@proj4string@projargs) & !is.null(supplyprojection)) 
    sp@proj4string@projargs <- supplyprojection
  if (is.na(sp@proj4string@projargs)) 
    stop("Shapefile projection information is missing.  Use supplyprojection= to specify a Proj.4 projection to use.  If the input shapefile is in WGS84 geographic (long-lat) coordinates, this will be +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 (in double-quotes).  If so, it must also be reprojected using reproject=.")
  proj4 <- strsplit(sp@proj4string@projargs, split = " ")
  projected <- sp::is.projected(sp)
  if (is.null(reproject) & !projected) 
    stop("Distances can only be computed from a projected coordinate system. Use reproject= to specify a Proj.4 projection to use.")
  if (!is.null(reproject)) {
    sp <- sp::spTransform(sp, sp::CRS(reproject))
    proj4 <- strsplit(sp@proj4string@projargs, split = " ")
  }
  units <- "unknown"
  for (i in 1:length(proj4[[1]])) {
    if (proj4[[1]][i] != "") {
      proj4arg <- strsplit(proj4[[1]][i], split = "=")
      if (proj4arg[[1]][1] == "+units") {
        units <- proj4arg[[1]][2]
        cat("\n", "Units:", proj4arg[[1]][2], "\n")
      }
    }
  }
  if (length(sp@lines) > 1) {
    sp_line <- NA
    sp_seg <- NA
    lines <- list()
    j <- 1
    for (i in 1:length(sp@lines)) {
      for (k in 1:length(sp@lines[i][[1]]@Lines)) {
        lines[[j]] <- sp@lines[i][[1]]@Lines[[k]]@coords
        sp_line[j] <- i
        sp_seg[j] <- k
        j <- j + 1
      }
    }
  }
  if (length(sp@lines) == 1) {
    lines <- sp@lines[1][[1]]@Lines
    length <- length(lines)
    lines.new <- list()
    for (i in 1:length) {
      lines.new[[i]] <- lines[[i]]@coords
    }
    lines <- lines.new
    sp_line <- rep(1, length)
    sp_seg <- 1:length
  }
  length <- length(lines)
  rivID <- 1:length
  lineID <- data.frame(rivID, sp_line, sp_seg)
  connections <- calculateconnections(lines = lines, tolerance = tolerance)
  if (any(connections %in% 5:6)) 
    braided <- TRUE
  lengths <- rep(NA, length)
  for (i in 1:length) {
    lengths[i] <- pdisttot(lines[[i]])
  }
  names <- rep(NA, length)
  mouth.seg <- NA
  mouth.vert <- NA
  mouth <- list(mouth.seg, mouth.vert)
  names(mouth) <- c("mouth.seg", "mouth.vert")
  sequenced <- FALSE
  braided <- NA
  cumuldist <- list()
  for (i in 1:length) {
    xy <- lines[[i]]
    n <- dim(xy)[1]
    cumuldist[[i]] <- c(0, cumsum(sqrt(((xy[1:(n - 1), 1] - 
                                           xy[2:n, 1])^2) + ((xy[1:(n - 1),    2] - xy[2:n, 2])^2))))
  }
  out.names <- c("sp", "lineID", "lines", "connections", "lengths", 
                 "names", "mouth", "sequenced", "tolerance", "units", 
                 "braided", "cumuldist")
  out <- list(sp, lineID, lines, connections, lengths, names, 
              mouth, sequenced, tolerance, units, braided, cumuldist)
  names(out) <- out.names
  class(out) <- "rivernetwork"
  length1 <- length(out$lengths)
  suppressMessages(out <- removeduplicates(out))
  length2 <- length(out$lengths)
  if (length2 < length1) 
    cat("\n", "Removed", length1 - length2, "duplicate segments.", "\n")

  # THIS LINE CAUSES ISSUES COMENT IT OUT
  # THIS LINE CAUSES ISSUES COMENT IT OUT
  # suppressMessages(out <- removemicrosegs(out))

  length3 <- length(out$lengths)
  if (length3 < length2) 
    cat("\n", "Removed", length2 - length3, "segments with lengths shorter than the connectivity tolerance.", "\n")
  return(out)
}

limpopo <- my.custom.line2network(path = "/Volumes/Shadowfax/Distribution/simple rivers/Limpopo.shp", 
                                  layer = "Limpopo", 
                                  tolerance = 100, 
                                  reproject = NULL,
                                  supplyprojection = NULL)
#displaying
plot(limpopo)

#Convert XY to river location
library(readxl)
limpopo_eel <- read_excel("/Volumes/Shadowfax/Distribution/Eel_data/limpopo_eel.xlsx")
View(limpopo_eel)

Limpopo_eel_riv <- xy2segvert(x=limpopo_eel$X, y=limpopo_eel$Y, rivers=limpopo)
hist(Limpopo_eel_riv$snapdist, main="snapping distance (m)")


#displaying point data in river location 
zoomtoseg(seg=c(4,3), rivers=limpopo)
points(limpopo_eel$X, limpopo_eel$Y, pch=16, col="red")
riverpoints(seg=Limpopo_eel_riv$seg, vert=Limpopo_eel_riv$vert, rivers=limpopo, pch=15, 
            col="blue")

#Computing a a matrix between all observations
dmat <- riverdistancemat(Limpopo_eel_riv$seg,Limpopo_eel_riv$vert,limpopo)

# starting location: segment 5, vertex 93
# ending location: segment 4, vertex 2420
detectroute(start=4, end=4, rivers=limpopo)
riverdistance(startseg=4, startvert=93, endseg=4, endvert=2420, rivers=limpopo, map=TRUE)
nter code here
```

And it get me this [Erro riverdist when calculating distance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FJQz.jpg)

Comment: Is it possible to provide a link where we can download the `Limpopo.shp` file and so that we can try to replicate your result please? This will help in trying to figure out a solution.

Comment: Added to the original post, thanks !

Comment: Were you able to get the desired result with the code in the answer I provided?

Comment: Unfortuantely no. I've edited the original post (not sure if i was supposed to post an answer rather ?). I think my shp file projection is the issue though. When the file is loaded onto GIS, it's not right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the`riverdist` package or the `line2network()` function, however, it is possible to modify the `line2network()` a little to force it to work in this situation. There is a line in the function which causes an issue.

```
# Create your custom function to read the file. 
# Examine the line2network function and modify the lines that cause an issue with your specific shape file

my.custom.line2network =  function (path = ".", layer, tolerance = 100, reproject = NULL, supplyprojection = NULL) {
sp <- suppressWarnings(rgdal::readOGR(dsn = path, layer = layer, verbose = F))
  if (class(sp) != "SpatialLinesDataFrame") 
    stop("Specified shapefile is not a linear feature.")
  if (is.na(sp@proj4string@projargs) & !is.null(supplyprojection)) 
    sp@proj4string@projargs <- supplyprojection
  if (is.na(sp@proj4string@projargs)) 
    stop("Shapefile projection information is missing.  Use supplyprojection= to specify a Proj.4 projection to use.  If the input shapefile is in WGS84 geographic (long-lat) coordinates, this will be +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 (in double-quotes).  If so, it must also be reprojected using reproject=.")
  proj4 <- strsplit(sp@proj4string@projargs, split = " ")
  projected <- sp::is.projected(sp)
  if (is.null(reproject) & !projected) 
    stop("Distances can only be computed from a projected coordinate system. Use reproject= to specify a Proj.4 projection to use.")
  if (!is.null(reproject)) {
    sp <- sp::spTransform(sp, sp::CRS(reproject))
    proj4 <- strsplit(sp@proj4string@projargs, split = " ")
  }
  units <- "unknown"
  for (i in 1:length(proj4[[1]])) {
    if (proj4[[1]][i] != "") {
      proj4arg <- strsplit(proj4[[1]][i], split = "=")
      if (proj4arg[[1]][1] == "+units") {
        units <- proj4arg[[1]][2]
        cat("\n", "Units:", proj4arg[[1]][2], "\n")
      }
    }
  }
  if (length(sp@lines) > 1) {
    sp_line <- NA
    sp_seg <- NA
    lines <- list()
    j <- 1
    for (i in 1:length(sp@lines)) {
      for (k in 1:length(sp@lines[i][[1]]@Lines)) {
        lines[[j]] <- sp@lines[i][[1]]@Lines[[k]]@coords
        sp_line[j] <- i
        sp_seg[j] <- k
        j <- j + 1
      }
    }
  }
  if (length(sp@lines) == 1) {
    lines <- sp@lines[1][[1]]@Lines
    length <- length(lines)
    lines.new <- list()
    for (i in 1:length) {
      lines.new[[i]] <- lines[[i]]@coords
    }
    lines <- lines.new
    sp_line <- rep(1, length)
    sp_seg <- 1:length
  }
  length <- length(lines)
  rivID <- 1:length
  lineID <- data.frame(rivID, sp_line, sp_seg)
  connections <- calculateconnections(lines = lines, tolerance = tolerance)
  if (any(connections %in% 5:6)) 
    braided <- TRUE
  lengths <- rep(NA, length)
  for (i in 1:length) {
    lengths[i] <- pdisttot(lines[[i]])
  }
  names <- rep(NA, length)
  mouth.seg <- NA
  mouth.vert <- NA
  mouth <- list(mouth.seg, mouth.vert)
  names(mouth) <- c("mouth.seg", "mouth.vert")
  sequenced <- FALSE
  braided <- NA
  cumuldist <- list()
  for (i in 1:length) {
    xy <- lines[[i]]
    n <- dim(xy)[1]
    cumuldist[[i]] <- c(0, cumsum(sqrt(((xy[1:(n - 1), 1] - 
                                           xy[2:n, 1])^2) + ((xy[1:(n - 1),    2] - xy[2:n, 2])^2))))
  }
  out.names <- c("sp", "lineID", "lines", "connections", "lengths", 
             "names", "mouth", "sequenced", "tolerance", "units", 
             "braided", "cumuldist")
  out <- list(sp, lineID, lines, connections, lengths, names, 
          mouth, sequenced, tolerance, units, braided, cumuldist)
  names(out) <- out.names
  class(out) <- "rivernetwork"
  length1 <- length(out$lengths)
  suppressMessages(out <- removeduplicates(out))
  length2 <- length(out$lengths)
  if (length2 < length1) 
    cat("\n", "Removed", length1 - length2, "duplicate segments.", "\n")

  # THIS LINE CAUSES ISSUES COMENT IT OUT
  # THIS LINE CAUSES ISSUES COMENT IT OUT
  # suppressMessages(out <- removemicrosegs(out))

  length3 <- length(out$lengths)
  if (length3 < length2) 
    cat("\n", "Removed", length2 - length3, "segments with lengths shorter than the connectivity tolerance.", "\n")
  return(out)
}
```

Now you can read the shape file using the new function you have just created

```
limpopo <- my.custom.line2network(path = "/Volumes/Shadowfax/Distribution/simple rivers/Limpopo.shp", 
                               layer = "Limpopo", 
                               tolerance = 100, 
                               reproject = NULL,
                               supplyprojection = NULL)
```

You should obtain the following plot:

[image: Limpopo river plot]

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved. Something wrong happened when saving my river shp with a projected CRS. With the projection being correct, the issue does not appear anymore.